# Oracle query taking too much of time when I use rownum

Tags: oracle

If I execute below query, it is returning results very fast.

```
(select * from 
select * from t1, t2 t3, t4 where ...(inner/outer join) group by ...) order by create_date desc)
```

How ever If I use ROWNUM like below, it is taking too much of time.

```
select * from (select * from 
select * from t1, t2 t3, t4 where ...(inner/outer join) group by ...) order by create_date desc) where rownum =1
```

could you please let me know why t is taking too much of time. How I can get latest date record.

Comment: you will get your answer in this link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307152/where-rownum-1-query-taking-time-in-oracle

Comment: Use MAX(create_date) to get the latest record

Answer (score 1):

Are you see **all** returning results for first query or are you see first few rows and you don't wait last row?
I think in second query, first works internal query and after the condition "rownum =1" check all result records

Comment: I want only one record which has latest date.

Comment: The inner query returns only 4 records.